# How to install a skin Cinnamon in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, cinnamon

Please tell me how to install Cinnamon shell in Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following commands in a terminal to install cinnamon:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

If the package is not available, you need to enable the universe repository.